# Oracle modify cursor value during loop

Tags: oracle, cursor

The following code compiles and works:

```
begin

  for l in (select 1 as v
              from dual
            union
            select 2 as v
              from dual
            union
            select 3 as v
              from dual) loop

              if l.v = 3 then
                l.v := 3.14; -- > modify the cursor value ?!
              end if;

              dbms_output.put_line('=> ' || l.v);

  end loop;

end;
```

> => 1
>   => 2
>   => 3.14

Is it good practice to do that in a loop, e.g. modify the value of the cursor?

What are the impacts of doing so? If I had declared the `select` in a cursor,  does it modify the value when i read again the cursor?

Thanks

Comment: `l` is a variable, it.s value is stored in memory, it's value is populated from the cursor by FOR...IN loop. If you assign a new value to `l`, you change the value of variable stored in memory, the row in the table is not changed. If you are going to change rows in the table, use [WHERE CURRENT OF clause](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/cursors/current_of.php). Using an assignment in order to change a value of variable is difficult to consider a bad practice. it's common operation.